# Unable to mount windows hard drive on linux live usb

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, usb

I am fully shutting down windows with "shutdown /s /t 0".
I also tried "shutdown /s /f /t 0" 
I then insert my linux live usb and boot from it. Everything works fine, but when I try to access my windows partition, it says that windows in hibernating. How do I fix this? Am I doing something wrong while turning on my computer in bios?

"Unable to access "480 GB Volume"
 Error mounting /dev/sda2 at media/ubuntu..."
Later it says:
"The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows"

I want to be able to read AND write to the windows hardisk btw

However, this live usb works perfectly on my other windows 8 computer. I can access the windows partition just fine on that (read and write).

Any tips?

NOTE:
I also did make it so that everytime I turn it off, it shutdowns completely. But it still isn't working :(
It works on all the other computers I have tried though

Comment: **Hibernating** is not the same as **Turned Off**

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: **Restart** your Windows 8 PC (`shutdown /r`).

Option 2: Disable Fast StartUp in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

windows 8 use fast boot mode it keeps windows 8 in hibernation and block windows partitions. To use these windows partitions stop fast boot mode. This change will give you access to windows partitions but increase time of windows boot.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.